# Formcalc nested if statement

Tags: forms, livecycle

I have been trying to figure out nested if statements in formcalc and for some reason I just can't get it to work.

The script is on formcalc and the first below script works but the problem is if totalNum is zero then the form throws an error because of the division by zero.

```
    var Vprt = confirmedSources.voltot/totalNum * 100


if(Vprt > 15)then
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "visible"
else
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "hidden"
    cansubmitending.presence = "hidden"
endif

   $.rawValue = Vprt
```

I tried this instead:

```
    If (totalNum  >0) then
         var Vprt = confirmedSources.voltot/totalNum * 100
    if(Vprt > 15) then
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "visible"
else
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "hidden"
    cansubmitending.presence = "hidden"
endif

   $.rawValue = Vprt
```

I also tried this:

```
    If (totalNum>0) then
         var Vprt = confirmedSources.voltot/totalNum * 100
    if(Vprt > 15) then
            $.rawValue = Vprt
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "visible"
else
    CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "hidden"
    cansubmitending.presence = "hidden"
    else
         $.rawValue = null
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In formcalc, you need an endif statement for each if statement, e.g.

```
If (totalNum  >0) then
    var Vprt = confirmedSources.voltot/totalNum * 100
    if(Vprt > 15) then
        CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "visible"
    else
        CANNOTSUBMITV.presence= "hidden"
        cansubmitending.presence = "hidden"
    endif

    $.rawValue = Vprt
endif
```